# Use React Toast Notification in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and Want to use react toast notification [offical docs](https://jossmac.github.io/react-toast-notifications/) in my project, On their official site they are using react hooks and using that to perform notification but I want to use that in class component on componentWillMount or componentDidMount. Is there any way I can do that or I have to use some other toast component. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a higher order component like `withToast` which will add that prop in your class based component

```js
import { useToasts } from 'react-toast-notifications'

function withToast(Component) {
  return function WrappedComponent(props) {
    const toastFuncs = useToasts()
    return <Component {...props} {...toastFuncs} />;
  }
}

//In you class component file

class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.addToast('Hello Toast');
  }
  
  render () {
    return <div>Toasts</div>
  }
}

export default withToast(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Added this answer to github issue as well

Comment: this error I am getting 
The `useToasts` hook must be called from a descendent of the `ToastProvider`.

Comment: React the docs, you need to wrap your app with ToastProvider like `<ToastProvider><App /></ToastProvider>

Comment: Read the docs. https://github.com/jossmac/react-toast-notifications

Comment: @IrtazaHussain You have not marked the correct answer yet

Comment: I moved to the react-toastify component